# Editing Google Docs from Web View in Android

Tags: android, excel, google-apps-script, android-webview, google-docs-api

I am developing an Android App in which I am providing below functionalities:

1) EditText in which user will enter URL and press submit button.

2) The URL will be the URL of Google docs spreadsheet (xls).

3) After submitting URL, web view is loaded with the details (spreadsheet from Google Docs).

Now the user should be able to edit the spreadsheet in Google Docs present inside WebView.

My problem is that I am not able to modify the Google Doc (spreadsheet xls)  at all. I've seen this in Google Chrome browser where user can edit the Google Docs.

Is there any way to achieve this in WebView? How can I achieve it with or without using WebView?

Comment: maybe `webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` will do the trick?

Comment: Yes, I have already use this.

Answer (score 1):

Extract from the [webview doc page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) :

*By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored. If your goal is only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine; the user won't need to interact with the web page beyond reading it, and the web page won't need to interact with the user. If you actually want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a WebView*

in bold : **and the web page won't need to interact with the user**

Google drive (and spreadsheets and docs etc...) is a platform (or should I say an environment) that by definition requires javascript (among other things a modern browser offers, take a look at the source code of a browser page to get an idea of what happens) to work.

The answer is definitely no.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But I have also seen this in other mobile browser where I was not able to edit Google Docs.(Even in Google chrome browser version of mobile). Is there any other alternative way to edit google docs online. Google driver api will work for this?

Comment: My app is kind of hybrid app where the user can view the web page. Hence, i am not invoking external browser.